# Object.defineProperty "undefining" value Attribute in a Prototypal Object Creation Pattern

Tags: javascript

When using object literal notation to create a Javascript Object like so:

```
var objectLiteralCat = {
  name: {first: 'frisky', last: 'LaBeouf'},
  color: 'Red'
}
```

I can then alter an Attribute of the `name` Property of `objectLiteralCat` like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(objectLiteralCat,'name', {configurable: false});
```

Great, now no one else can delete the `objectLiteralCat.name` Property or alter its enumerable Attribute.

I am experimenting with a "flavor" of prototypal pattern object creating and I would like to use Object.defineProperty to set the name Property Attribute `configurable` = `false` like above, here is the code:

```js
var Cat = {
  create: function(firstName, lastName, color){
    var self = Object.create(this);
    self.name.first = firstName;
    self.name.last = lastName;
    Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false});
    Object.freeze(self.name);
    Object.freeze(self.color);
    return self;
  },
  name: {first: '', last: ''},
  color: ''
}

var cat = Cat.create('frisky','smith','white');
console.log(cat.name); //undefined
```

If, in the `Cat.create` function I comment out the line:

```
Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false});
```

Then `console.log(cat.name)` outputs, as expected:

```
Object {first: "frisky", last: "smith"}
```

I can explicitly set the `value` Attribute of the `Cat.name` Property like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {value: self.name, configurable: false});
```

What I do not not understand is why doesn't the `objectLiteralCat` call to `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(objectLiteralCat,'name', {configurable: false});
```

set the the `objectLiteralCat.name` to `undefined` like:

```
Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false});
```

does in my `Cat.create` function?

Even if I comment out the `Object.define` code in `Cat.create` and move it outside after the `cat` object is created like so:

```
var cat = Cat.create('fluffy', 'leboudf', 'white');
Object.defineProperty(cat,'name', {configurable: false});
console.log(cat.name);
```

The output of `console.log(cat.name)` is again `undefined`.

My `objectLiteralCat` object:

```
Object {
    name: [object Object]
    color: Red
}
```

looks fundamentally the same to my "flavor of prototypal pattern object creation"

```
Object {
    create: function(firstName, lastName, color){
        var self = Object.create(this);
        self.name.first = firstName;
        self.name.last = lastName;
        //Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {value: self.name, configurable: false});
        Object.freeze(self.name);
        Object.freeze(self.color);
        return self;
    }
    name: [object Object]
    color:
}
```

Looking at the `console.log` of the two objects though, it looks like all the Properties of the object created with `Cat.create` are nested in `__proto__`

[image]

I am sure that is a clue to the answer to my question but I am not advanced enough yet with Javascript to figure out the answer without help.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [the examples on MDN's documentation of `defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). They have some that are very close to what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that, in your object literal, `objectLiteralCat.name` refers to the `name` object immediately on `objectLiteralCat`. On the other hand, when calling `Cat.create`, you make *two* `name`s: one is on the prototype object (the object at `Cat.name`), and the other is on the `self` object. `Object.defineProperty` does not look up the prototype chain to identify where/if the passed property name passed is on any of the prototype objects - rather, `Object.defineProperty` defines the property *immediately on the object passed to it*, which in this case, is `self`.

But, before

```
Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false});
```

is called, references to `self.name` - that is, in the lines

```
self.name.first = firstName;
self.name.last = lastName;
```

will refer to the closest object in the prototype chain with a `name` property - which is the `Cat.name` object. To illustrate, see how instantiating a cat mutates the `Cat.name` prototype object:

```js
var Cat = {
  create: function(firstName, lastName, color){
    var self = Object.create(this);
    self.name.first = firstName;
    self.name.last = lastName;
    Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false});
    Object.freeze(self.name);
    Object.freeze(self.color);
    return self;
  },
  name: {first: '', last: ''},
  color: ''
}

var cat = Cat.create('frisky','smith','white');

// Log the prototype object: it's been mutated!
console.log(Cat.name);
```

After that, when you call

```
Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false});
```

this sets the `name` property *directly on* `self`, not on the prototype. But you haven't passed any `value` to it, so it defaults to `undefined`. The `name` property now exists *both* on the prototype object (`Cat.name.first` and `Cat.name.last`), *and* on the instantiated `cat` (=== `undefined`).

Perhaps you want to explicitly create a new `name` property directly on `self` at the beginning, *before* assigning to `self.name.first`:

```js
var Cat = {
  create: function(firstName, lastName, color){
    var self = Object.create(this);
    Object.defineProperty(self,'name', {configurable: false, value: {}});
    self.name.first = firstName;
    self.name.last = lastName;
    Object.freeze(self.name);
    Object.freeze(self.color);
    return self;
  },
  name: {first: '', last: ''},
  color: ''
}

var cat = Cat.create('frisky','smith','white');
console.log(cat.name);
```

Comment: great explanation, thank you much I understand clearly now and it makes perfect sense. A lightbulb just went of in my head regarding prototypal inheritance in general as well, SWEET :)

Answer (score 2):

While `self` is a new instance inheriting the `Cat` object, `self.name` still references the global `Cat.name`. Therefore if you do:

```
const obj = { prop: 1 }
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", { /*...*/ })
```

Its a different thing, as the property *exists directly on the object itself* and and is not inherited. If it gets inherited, e.g.:

```
const obj2 = Object.create(obj);
Object.defineProperty(obj2, "prop", {/*...*/})
```

then `defineProperty` defines a *new property on the object itself*. It does not consider that it was set on the prototype already. Therefore you shadow it to undefined. To solve that you might wanna assign a new object for every instance, e.g.:

```
self.name = { first: firstName, last: lastName};
```

Comment: Thank you much for your answer, much appreciated